# FileInput/outputstream not working

Tags: java, file, inputstream, outputstream

i have a simple input/output stream here:

```
package managingfilesanddirectories;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("selfie.jpg");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("newPic.jpg");) {
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

All files are in the same package, but whenever i try to make a new file, the new files are not created (both with .jpg, -and .txt files). I'm using netbeans, should i place the files in another package or directory?
[image]

i get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file   specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at managingfilesanddirectories.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: Please replace `e.getMessage()` with `e.printStackTrace()` to know if there were some exceptions in your catch blocks.

Comment: Does it throw a exception? What is the default directory where you run your app in?

Comment: Exception has been added. There is no default directory, since i just add the file name, and they are in the same package (for testing purposes)

Comment: You are not showing the whole code. Current code does nothing with `test.txt` file.

Comment: @MarceloTataje OP is using twr. What are you saying?

Comment: @tsolakp i'm showing everything. The goal is to make an exact copy of the file, this is why i'm writing out using the input/output stream.

Comment: @kryptering. I dont think so. Even your stack trace line numbers dont align with the code you put in the question.

Comment: It does, what more should i add then? It works fine, apart from the fact, that i does not find the file.

Comment: @kryptering, please add the following line before `try(){}` block to check where does your code expects file to be located `System.out.println(new File("qwerty").getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score -1):

For working with FileInputStream or FileOutputStream you shoukd sent ti constructor File. 
For example:

```
File myFile = new File("C:\\exampleFile.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream;
try {
     inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
     // reading from input stream
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
     inputStream.close();
}
```

For better you should check that file and path are exists.

Comment: You dont need to pass `File` object to `FileInputStream`. `FileInputStream` can take a relative path as string and create the file if it does not exist relative to where JVM is started.

Comment: There's no need to pass a file object to File Input/Output Stream. File names will work just fine. See javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: Yes, but you need to write a full path to file in constructor

Comment: Do you set the full path of file?